# Determining point in level set, so Jacobian Matrix has a rank less than 2

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

So I have found a Jacobian Matrix from the parametric curve,

$f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2,(x-1)^2+y^2)$

with the level set L=$\{(x,y,z)\in R^3\vert f(x,y,z)=(4,a^2)\}$.

I found the Jacobian Matrix to be as seen right below to the right.
\begin{pmatrix}
2x & 2y & 2z\\
2x-2 & 2y & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
I have to find the points in L, which makes the rank of the Jacobian Matrix less than 2 while $0<a<3$.
I have converted it to reduced echelon form, but it doesn't seem like it's possible to determine any points that make the rank strictly less than 2, since there is always going to be a leading entrance with a 1, in the second row.
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & z\\
0 & 1 & \frac{z}{y}(x-1)\\
\end{pmatrix}
What is it I'm not understanding?

Comment: What happens if you take a point with $y=z=0$? Be careful when you do your row operations that you're not dividing by $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Say I multiply that row with y again, so we no longer have the possibility of dividing with 0. My initial answer to the assignment was that x=1 and y=0 for the rank of the Jacobian to be of smaller rank than 2. But that has somehow been graded poorly, so what do I do?

Comment: I do not follow what you're saying. You get the echelon form $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & y & z\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @TedShifrin Ahhhhh, now I get your comment. That also gives me an a that's actually in L. I might be inadequate at row operations. Is that what you did to reduce it?

Comment: First of all, divide everything by $2$. Subtracting the first row from the second gives you a row $[-1 \ 0 \ 0]$. Now finish.

Comment: @TedShifrin Doesn’t that give you $[-1\;0\;-z]$ instead?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I was doing stuff away from my computer at my desk. So we should have $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & z \\ 0 & y & z(1-x)\end{bmatrix}$.  So we have rank $<2$ when $y=z=0$ *or* when $y=0$ and $x=1$. My apologies, again.

Comment: No worries, it was the one I found and stuck with as well. Regardless this helped me a great deal. Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful when row-reducing matrices that have variable entries. You need to examine cases in which you might have divided by zero separately. Be especially wary if you use automated solvers to do your row-reduction for you. Most of them don’t handle variable entries the way one might like and will happily spit out a full rank matrix even if some values of those variables actually produce a rank-deficient matrix. This is the case here: if you ask Mathematica to row-reduce your Jacobian, it will produce a full-rank matrix—in fact the one you have in your question—even though the Jacobian is obviously rank-one when $y=z=0$.

This problem can be solved without using row-reduction at all, which avoids all of these considerations (although row-reduction is pretty easy here). Your Jacobian is rank-deficient iff one row is a scalar multiple of the other, which can be expressed as $(2x,2y,2z)\times(2x-2,2y,0)=0$. This will give you three equations in $x$, $y$ and $z$, although one of them will be redundant. If you prefer not to take advantage of special features of $\mathbb R^3$, then you can instead examine the three $2\times2$ minors of the Jacobian: it is rank-deficient iff they all vanish. This condition in fact generates same three equations for your Jacobian as does the cross-product equation above.

Comment: Yeah, that makes total sense. First time I had to deal with row reduction with variables and I don't think we're allowed to use cross product for this one, as it's presented for the next week's assignment. Thanks a lot for taking out the time to help me!